# Removing symmetric pairs using a list comprehension (using notin in a list comprehension)

Tags: rascal

I have this function where I remove symmetrics pairs from a list relation, works fine but I was curious if it would be possible to rewrite this to a list comprehension.

```
lrel[str,str] newClonePairs = [];
for (tuple[str L, str R] pair <- clonePairs) {
    if (<pair.R, pair.L> notin newClonePairs) {     
        newClonePairs += pair;
    }
}

return newClonePairs;
```

I got this far (see code below), but how do you then write the `notin` part? Is there some kind of keyword which can be used to refer to the current list?

```
return [pair | tuple[tuple[node,loc] L,tuple[node,loc] R] pair <- clonePairs, <pair.R, pair.L> notin thisCurrentList];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list you are generating can not be referred to during a list comprehension. With a reducer you could, but I don't think it would be very fast.

How about this one:

```
[ <L, R> | [*_, <L,R>, *post] := clonePairs,  <R,L> notin post ]
```

It will loop through all `<L,R>` pairs, and add only the ones which are not found in the rest of the list.

It works via "list matching". A list pattern can contain variables with a `*` in front which will match a sub-list of any length (including the empty list). Such a match is usually not unique (for example above the `<L,R>` in the middle can be anywhere in the list because `*_` and `*post` can be of any length). If a list pattern can match a list in many ways, then it becomes a generator and the `:=` will loop through all the matches from left to right similar to the behaviour of `<-`. See also: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Patterns/Abstract/List/List.html

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! Just what I was looking for. But is it possible to elaborate a bit more on the [*_, <L,R>, *post] part? Are these three seperate patterns the match operator applies to? And what is the meaning of the * exactly?